# Why can an int hold a 10 digits number but can't handle 9 digits of another integer?

Tags: c, memory

This may have been answered already and I am not exactly sure how to word it, but here goes nothing. I'm compiling using ***gcc*** on Linux. My question is why will the compiler throw an overflow warning when I assign ten 9's to an `int` variable, but won't when I assign the value "1234567891", which uses ten digits. It will if I assign the value "12345678912".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 1234567891;
    int b = 9999999999;

    printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

> test.c:6:11: warning: overflow in conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘int’ changes value from ‘9999999999’ to ‘1410065407’ [-Woverflow]
>     int b = 9999999999;
>
> test.c:6:11: warning: overflow in conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘int’ changes value from ‘12345678912’ to ‘-539222976’ [-Woverflow]
>     int b = 12345678912;

Output of just the ten integers:

> ~/Programming$ ./a.out 
>   1234567891

Comment: Computers don't count in base 10 (with digits 0-9) as humans mostly do, they count in base 2 (digits 0-1/bits). In base 2, 9999999999 requires more than the 32 bits (or rather 31 + one which is only helping represent negative numbers) which is the limit for an `int`, while 1234567891 will fit.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Some did like the HP Series 80... the processor could calculate base 10. But that was some time ago :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the number of "places" in base 10 or, if you prefer, the length of the number when you write it out (again, in base 10). The most basic reason for the limitation is that computers store numbers (and everything else) in terms of bits and bytes, which means they work in base 2.

An `int` in c is a 4-byte (32-bit) datatype. It can store numbers in the range -2,147,483,648 (-2<sup>31</sup>) to 2,147,483,647 (2<sup>31</sup> - 1) if the `int` is signed or 0 to 4,294,967,295 (2<sup>32</sup>-1) if it is not.

Either way, 1234567891 is in the range that fits in 4 bytes, but 9999999999 and 12345678912 are not.

---

Note: I recognize the spec allows for an `int` to be 2 bytes, but the behavior OP describes is only possible if OP is using an implementation in which an `int` is 4 bytes.

Comment: So what byte datatype is the ten 9s

Comment: It's not a "byte datatype." It's just a datatype. And it would be `long int`, or, if you *really* want to store big numbers, `long long int`.

Comment: I'm going to choose you for the best answer for being descriptive and helpful but I got one last question to bug you with. Where would I go or how would I word it in order to find resources to understand this memory and data typing better. I'm sorry if it's a stupid question but I struggle with numbers to be honest and want to learn this badly.

Comment: Just search this site, Google, or your favorite other search engine for “c datatypes” (or “c data types”—the space won’t matter). You should be able to find a list with all of the various sizes and ranges pretty easily. You’ll probably also want to walk through some basic tutorials before going any further. Coding in c is very difficult when you know all the basics already, but it’s almost impossible before you learn all the data types and basic storage/memory concepts.